# Redirecting contact form in SwiftMailer to success page doesn't work

Tags: php, redirect, swiftmailer

I don't know a thing about php but with little help and research I managed to set up working contact form with Swift Mailer. It's sending messages alright but I want it to redirect people, after sending message, to thank_you.html page. I tried everything I could but it does not work. Could you help me? Here is the code:

```
<?php

include("Swift/lib/swift_required.php"); 
$host = 'xxxxxx.xxxxxx@gmail.com';
$password = 'xxxxx'; 
$subject = "zapytanie ze strony"; 
$body = "Zglaszajacy: ".$_POST["fullname"]."\r\n";
$body .= "Telefon: ".$_POST["phone"]."\r\n";
$body .= "E-mail: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$body .= "Tresc: ".$_POST["description"]."\r\n";

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl') 
->setUsername($host)
->setPassword($password);

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
->setFrom(array($host => 'Klient')) 
->setTo(array('xxxxxxx@xxxx.gmail.com'=> 'xxxxxx'))
->setBody($body);

$result = $mailer->send($message); 
if ($result) 
{ 
    header('Location: http://www.xxxxx.org/thank_you.html'); 
}
echo $result;


?>
```

I added that part myself:

```
if ($result) 
{ 
    header('Location: http://www.xxxxx.org/thank_you.html'); 
}
```

and it does not work. Mail is sent but nothing is happening with form. It just stays there. Please treat me like a total layman in this one ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the php documentation for [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

It's likely that some whitespace is being output either by your code or the included swift mailer code before reaching your call to `header`.

Try using [`ob_start()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) at the start of your code, then [`ob_end_flush()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) at the end.